# Ratios of random integer triples chosen in interval 1 to N.

Tags: statistics

When looking at the moments of inertia of random 3D walks, the question arose what the expected mean and variance would be for the ratios j/i  and k/i of three random integers chosen in the interval 1 .. N and sorting them such that  i<= j<= k.
Numerical experimentation with sample size $s$ seems to indicate a different behaviour for $s$ << N than for $s$ >> N.
In the first case, j/i approaches $\frac 23 \log_2 s$ and k/i looks like $\frac 54 \log_2 s$. The standard deviations $\sigma$  seem to be obey $\log( \sigma / \log_2 s) = 0.272 \log_2 s -1.64$ and  $\log( \sigma / \log_2 s) = 0.276 \log_2 s -1.16$ respectively.
(This looks like a Lambert W type functional relationship.)
For the case $ s \sim N$ the numerics jump all over the place, as if there were something ill-defined in this regime.

question 1: what are the limits for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in the regime s << N ?
question 2: why the erratic behaviour at $s \sim N$ and $s \gt N$ ?

Comment: What is your definition of "three integers $i \le j \le k$ randomly chosen in the interval $[1, N]$"? "Randomly chosen" how? Are you choosing three numbers separately, then labelling them $i,j,k$ based on their order? Or are you choosing $i$ first, then $j$ from the values $\ge i$, then $k$ from the values $\ge j$? Or are you doing something else? Note that by the first method, $i=N,j=N,k=N$ has a $1/N^3$ chance of occurring, but by the second, it has a  $1/N$ chance of occurring.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: question edited to indicate the first method. The idea is to get a comparison with triples of integers resulting from a non-random problem.

Comment: The sample space is $N^3$, so you need a larger sample size ($s>N$) to obtain meaningful results. Also, the expected values for $\frac{j}{i}$ and $\frac{k}{i}$ increase with $N$.

Comment: @DanielMathias: the regime s<N is well-behaved and gives meaningful results. For N=10 or 100 and s up to 10^8 the results are erratic.

Comment: For $N=100$ and $s>1000$ the mean values $4.42$ and $7.84$ are consistently approximated. With $s=50$ the results are inconsistent. The erratic behavior you are seeing is likely due to your code. Be sure to use double-precision floating-point variables.